# Add a few months to bootstrap DateTimePicker calendar after change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the date picker from [eonasdan](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I am trying to add three months to the second calendar as soon as I pick a date from the first. I have tried using the `moment().add(3,'M')` method, but it doesn't work as I am expecting it to. 
I'm just trying to do two simple, interrelated, tasks:

1. Add three months to the second calendar's `minDate`
2. Display that date in the calendar's `<input>` field. The JS for the calendars is below.

   ```
   $('#start-date').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent:false,format: 'D-M-YYYY'
   });

    $("#start-date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
       var probDate = new Date(e.date().add(3,'M'));

       $('#probation-date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
   });
   $("#end-date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
       $('#start-date').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
   });
   ```

I tried to made a JSFiddle, but there's no way to include external files via a CDN for this widget. It's MomentJS knowledge that I lack here.

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/3mbhfegc/1/ ?

Comment: @link2pk Yes, that's partially what i was looking for. Could you please make this into an answer that also shows how the date would be set automatically for the second calendar? Thanks